# Print page setup in PHP

Tags: php, printing

Am currently developing a web application which does the process of invoice etc.
Customer is using dot matrix printer to print invoice sheet. They said the requirement in printing as if there is more than 5 items in a sheet the rest should come as next sheet.
I have made that using PHP but i don't know how to print the next sheet in next page. It just prints as usual in sequence which results in a sheet printed in 2 pages. Any help or ideas will be appreciated. Below is the code how i generated sheet.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printPage(){
    var divElements = document.getElementById('printDataHolder').innerHTML;
    var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML="<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/common.css' type='text/css' /><body class='bodytext'>"+divElements+"</body>";
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
    }
</script>

    <?php
    $limit=5;
    $cnt=0; // for table header and footer
    $cnt2=1;// for no of rows count to print total values in end
    $total=0;
    ?>
    <div id="contentHolder" align="center">
    <input type="button" value="Print" class="btnclass" onclick="printPage()" /> <input type="button" class="btnclass" value="Click to Proceed" style="width:100px;" onclick="Javascript:window.location.href='invoice.php';" />
    <br />
    <div id="printDataHolder">
    <?php while($data=mysql_fetch_array($invcontents)){ ?>
    <?php if($cnt==0){ ?>
    <table width="800" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border:1px solid #4E9A91;">
      <tr>
        <td height="29" colspan="4" style="font-size:22px; padding-left:10px;"><strong>OvalTechnologies</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php echo($branchdetails['address']); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="19" colspan="4" style="padding-left:10px;">Website : www.ovaltechnologies.in&nbsp;&nbsp;Phone No : <?php echo($branchdetails['phoneno']); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="12" colspan="4" style="border-bottom:1px solid #4E9A91;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="28" colspan="3" style="padding-left:10px;">Customer Name : <?php echo($invtotal['customername']); ?></td>
        <td width="226">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="309" height="28" style="padding-left:10px;border-bottom:1px solid #4E9A91;">Invoice No : <?php echo($invoiceid); ?></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:1px solid #4E9A91;">Paid As : <?php echo($invtotal['paidas']); ?></td>
        <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #4E9A91;">Date : <?php echo(getonlydatefromdatetime(changefromdbdate($invtotal['invoicedate']))); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="28" class="rowborder" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Item Name</strong></td>
        <td width="136" class="rowborder"><strong>Rate</strong></td>
        <td width="129" class="rowborder"><strong>Qty</strong></td>
        <td class="rowborder"><strong>Amount</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" height="28" style="padding-left:10px;"><?php echo($data['item']); ?> : <?php echo($data['brand']." "); ?><?php echo($data['type']); ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo($data['billedamount']); ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo($data['quantity']); ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo($data['billedamount']*$data['quantity']); ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      if($cnt2==$invcount){//printing emptylines to fill up page
          for($i=$cnt+1;$i<$limit;$i++){
            ?>
             <tr>
            <td height="28" style="padding-left:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
          }
      }//printing emptylines to fill page ends
      ?>
      <?php if($cnt==$limit-1 || $cnt2==$invcount){ ?>
      <?php if($invtotal['transport']!="") {?>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:10px; border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;" class="rowborder" height="28">Transport : <?php echo($invtotal['transport']); ?></td>
        <td class="rowborder" style="border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;">Transport Cost : <?php echo($invtotal['transportcost']); ?></td>
        <td class="rowborder" style="border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;">Destination : <?php echo($invtotal['destination']); ?></td>
        <td class="rowborder" style="border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
      <tr>
        <td height="28" class="rowborder" style="border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="rowborder" style="border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;"><?php if($invtotal['transport']!="") {if($invtotal['addtransport']=="no"){echo("Transport Cost Not Added");}}?></td>
        <td class="rowborder" style="border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;">Total</td>
        <td class="rowborder" style="border-top:1px solid #4E9A91;"><?php echo($invtotal['totalamount']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="28">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">Invoice Done By</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table><br />
    <?php } ?>
    <?php 
    $cnt++;
    $cnt2++;
    if($cnt==$limit){
        $cnt=0;
    }
    } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php 
    } ?>
```

Comment: can i haz teh codez plz

Comment: printing sheet codes were updated

Answer (score 0):

do not see such options in  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printer-set-option.php

but you can have look around the functions here http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php

printer_start_doc — Start a new document 
printer_start_page — Start a new page